# Handling empty files when concatenating files in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a number (say, 100) of CSV files, out of which some (say, 20) are empty (i.e., 0 bytes file). I would like to concatenate the files into one single CSV file (say, `assorted.csv`), with the following requirement met:

For each empty file, there must be a blank line in `assorted.csv`.

It appears that simply doing `cat *.csv >> assorted.csv` skips the empty files completely in the sense that they do not have any lines and hence there is nothing to concatenate.

Though I can solve this problem using any high-level programming language, I would like to know if and how to make it possible using Bash.

Comment: You don't care which file the lines came from?

Comment: In the current requirements of mine, I do but each of my files contain only one line and the files follow a numbered naming convention so that is not a problem.

Comment: It would be very easy to tag each line...  Interested?

Comment: Well well !!! Count me  in  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a loop and detect if the file is not empty. If it's empty, just echo the file name+comma in it: that will create a near blank line.  Otherwise, prefix each line with the file name+comma.

```
#!/bin/bash

out=assorted.csv
# delete the file prior to doing concatenation
# or if ran twice it would be counted in the input files!
rm -f "$out"

for f in *.csv
do
   if [ -s "$f" ] ; then
      #cat "$f" | sed 's/^/$f,/'  # cat+sed is too much here
      sed "s/^/$f,/" "$f"
   else
      echo "$f,"
   fi
done > $out
```

Comment: Yeah !!. I was foolish not to go back to the basics and assuming that there must be a simpler one liner trick to do it. This is certainly possible. Thanks a lot. Accepting this.

Comment: Consider putting only one redirection after the `done` keyword, instead of opening the file multiple times!

Comment: The one liners for varying input are tough to find, but, you could do a 3 liner with ls and paste, I think...  Actually, join...  but it's a bit opaque...  (BTW, my edit for file prepending the file name is in review.)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf nice suggestion. Will edit (not now from my phone!)

Comment: edit+merged with BenPen edits according to OP wishes.

Comment: @BenPen left your line commented just in case someone decides to remove filename prefix. Easier to remove the `| sed` than trying to figure out `cat` again even if it's simple.

Comment: The done > $out line always surprises me, but such a cool feature.